# Functional difference between `coverage run -m pytest` and `pytest --cov=...`?

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

The Coverage tool supports generating code coverage data from Pytest tests with `coverage run -m pytest ...`. However, there is also the Pytest-Cov plugin, which invokes Coverage and generates coverage data by adding the `--cov=` option to Pytest.

However the Pytest-Cov documentation doesn't seem to explain anywhere how this differs from just using `coverage run`. Is there any practical difference, or is it just a matter of the options/configuration choices that are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences/advantages are mentioned on their [Github README](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov#readme) and [docs](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)

> Compared to just using `coverage run` this plugin does some extras:
>
> - Subprocess support: you can fork or run stuff in a subprocess and will get covered without any fuss.
> - Xdist support: you can use all of pytest-xdist's features and still get coverage.
> - Consistent pytest behavior. If you run `coverage run -m pytest` you will have slightly different `sys.path` (CWD will be in it, unlike
>   when running `pytest`).
>
> All features offered by the coverage package should work, either
> through pytest-cov's command line options or through coverage's config
> file.

Comment: Thanks! I realize now that this *is* found in their docs on this page: https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html?highlight=compared%20to%20just#overview